# Automatically remove older zipkin entries in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, zipkin

This is specifically for Zipkin's Elastic Search storage connector.  Which does not do the index that you can use Curator.

Is there a way of **automatically** removing old traces and have that as part of the ElasticSearch configuration (rather than building yet another service or cron job)  Since I am using it for a development server I just need it wiped every hour or so.

Answer (score 0):

From [zipkin docs](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/tree/master/zipkin-storage/elasticsearch#indexes):

> There is no support for TTL through this SpanStore. It is recommended instead to use Elastic Curator to remove indices older than the point you are interested in.